# Is there better method, performance wise, to do this?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, conditional-formatting

Is there, maybe, a faster method of cell referencing for conditional formatting?

code example:

```
For Each cell In irow
    For i = 1 To arr_size
        If cell > start(i) - arr1(i) And start(i) > Var1 And cell <= Var2 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next cell
```

Comment: Is this particularly slow? How long does it take? Over how many cells and what size of array?  Are you turning off screenupdating?

Comment: @Tim Williams Good question, if the condition is met it goes twice over 160 cells, the sizes of arrays are small up to 25. Problem is I have to run up to 40 macros like that at once. Yes I am turning off all of these..

Comment: @Tim Williams Oh I forgot.. one macro runs rather fast that is about 0.1 sec, 20 macros more than half second

Comment: Only thing that I can think off on how to speed this up is to join all cells that need colour in an array, and do the cokouring on that array at once at the end if your loops. Usually interacting with cells is what takes up the most time, so minimizing this from 40 to 1 could chip some time off.

Comment: @Luuklah Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Also try nesting your if tests instead of chasing with And. Tha way they will stop on the first False

Comment: @Tim Williams just to show why such relatively fast macro time is unnerving in my program :
!https://imgur.com/a/jkMwiFv

Comment: If you have up to 40 similar methods that may indicate some other possible approaches, but without more info it would be difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: And if you're coloring a contiguous block like that, you can try noting "start" and "end" cells and coloring the block in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be slightly faster:

```
Dim v, rng As Range

For Each cell In irow
    For i = 1 To arr_size
        If start(i) > Var1 Then
            v = cell.Value
            If v > start(i) - arr1(i) Then 
                If v <= Var2 Then
                    If rng Is Nothing then
                        Set rng = cell
                    Else
                        Set rng = aplication.union(rng, cell)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next cell

If Not rng Is Nothing then rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
```

Comment: It seems bit complicated approach given slight improvement but could you elaborate on 'coloring block in one shot' solution because I do have contiguous cells coloured. (Also I wish I could provide more code but the format here is limiting us), thank you

Comment: Given the information provided, you're only going to be looking at "slight" improvements.  By coloring blocks in one shot I mean not cell-by-cell: I already made that adjustment above, so I'm not sure how much further you could go in that direction.  There are maybe small changes you could make but it's difficult to make suggestions without the rest of the code and more information on the context.

Comment: I almost rewrote the code according to your formula and it really works, any improvement would be nice but this is noticeable indeed! And on excel 2016 it works almost fine now. To just say thank you is not enough!